# Calculating mean of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, spheres

What is the formula for calculating the mean of several points in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I don't see a similar question for this here.

I have calculated the centres of a set of sphere approximations and now need to calculate the mean centre. Would it be easiest to use spherical coordinates?

Comment: What's wrong with just adding them and dividing by the number of points?

Comment: Ok, so it is just the means of each of x, y, and z components?

Comment: If that works for whatever it is you need it for, then yes. But it doesn't work in spherical coordinates.